# dont show chart in convert from pdf to word in java with Aspose

Tags: java, aspose, aspose-cells, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I decided to convert excel to word but , I was suggested that I have to convert exccel to pdf , after this ok ,I convert pdf to word But Excel has a chart that correctly is in pdf Unfortunately, it does not come in Word.

```
import com.aspose.cells.FileFormatType;
import com.aspose.cells.Workbook;
import com.aspose.pdf.Document;
import com.aspose.pdf.SaveFormat;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String dir="D:/Test/";

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook(dir+"test.xlsx");

        workbook.save(dir+"testexcel.pdf", FileFormatType.PDF);

        Document document = new Document(dir+"testexcel.pdf");

        document.save(dir+"testexcel1.docx", SaveFormat.DocX);

    }
}
```

this is my excel :
https://ufile.io/8wruc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Saeed Aliakbari, Yes, it could be the cause of a missing chart. The trail version (without applying Aspose license) of Aspose.Pdf for Java API inserts an evaluation watermark, and only four elements of any collection can be viewed/edited. You can get a 30 day temporary license for the evaluation purposes. It would be a full license that lets you test every aspect of the API before buying it.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 2):

@Saeed Aliakbari,
I have executed your code to convert the source Excel to PDF, and then PDF to DOCX with Aspose.Cells for Java 17.6 and Aspose.Pdf for Java 17.6 APIs. We could not find the missing chart in the output DOCX file. This is the output DOCX file: [Output Word document of Aspose.Pdf for Java 17.6](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmj2kds2ns11vq9/OuputAsposePDF_17.6.docx?dl=0). You can highlight the issue with a snapshot and also let me know the problematic page number.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: I'm using a trial version, do you think the problem is this?

Comment: @Saeed Aliakbari, Yes, it could be the cause of a missing chart. The trail version (without applying Aspose license) of Aspose.Pdf for Java API inserts an evaluation watermark, and only four elements of any collection can be viewed/edited. You can get a 30 day temporary license for the evaluation purposes. It would be a full license that lets you test every aspect of the API before buying it.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.